# Issue getting localStorage data to persist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

I am making an app that tracks how many tasks you complete in a day. Once a task is completed the average number of tasks completed on that day is tracked relative to the total tasks completed all time. I want this to persist so I can display it but when I refresh the page it is not persisting.

When I console log the `avgWednesday` it updates correctly but once I refresh the page it goes back to `0`.

It is defined as:

```
const [avgWednesday, setAvgWednesday] = React.useState(0);
```

*This is all within a functional component as function app(){*

Function runs to calculate the average:

```
function addWednesday(){
  const currWednesday = totalWednesday + 1;
  setTotalWednesday(totalWednesday + 1);
  localStorage.setItem("storedTotalWednesday", currWednesday);

  const currTotalTasks = tasksFinishedTotal + 1;
  const wedAvg = (Math.round((currWednesday / currTotalTasks)*100));
  setAvgWednesday(wedAvg); 
  localStorage.setItem("storedAvgWed", avgWednesday);   //STORING HERE 
}
```

Using this to make it persist (for some reason never runs even when the average is updated):

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const savedWedAvg = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("storedAvgWed")) || 0;
  setAvgWednesday(savedWedAvg);
}, []);
```

Comment: Where is `avgWednesday` getting defined and set?

Comment: @HereticMonkey It's updated by `setAvgWednesday` but that's not happening immediately, I believe it's a state in a functional component.

Comment: I'm asking a leading question to confirm there is unseen use of `useState` hooks. I prefer to clarify rather than make assumptions... @norbitrial

Comment: @HereticMonkey Agree, I deleted my answer until then, maybe it's something else.

Comment: Sorry for the delay I've updated the code to specify how I defined it @Heret

Comment: What does the code for the `setAvgWednesday()` function look like?

Comment: @ADyson it's not a traditional function its a hook that sets the state of avgWednesday.

Comment: Does that mean it doesn't have code we can see? Sorry I'm not that familiar with React.

Comment: Anyway, have you used the debugger to check that, when you run `localStorage.setItem("storedAvgWed", avgWednesday);`, the value of avgWednesday is what you expect? That would tell you if it's being saved with the wrong value, rather than retrieved incorrectly.

Comment: @ADyson oh damn that was it I forgot React runs functions asynchronously so it was updating avgWednesday but also storing it as 0 since it happens at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Although you are expecting for `avgWednesday` to be updated by `setAvgWednesday` but it's not happening immediately.

The `setAvgWednesday` is *asynchronous*, you should call with `wedAvg` instead as:

```
setAvgWednesday(wedAvg); 
localStorage.setItem("storedAvgWed", wedAvg);
```

As `wedAvg` has been already calculated and it's in place.

Comment: This assumes unseen code like `const [avgWednesday, setAvgWednesday] = useState(0);`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out thanks to @ADyson the function runs asynchronously in React so I have to store wedAvg rather than avgWednesday (var holding the calculation rather than the value itself). Storing wedAvg would store 0 since the function runs every line at the same time, storing 0 rather than the actual updated average / calculation.

```
function addWednesday(){
  const currWednesday = totalWednesday + 1;
  setTotalWednesday(totalWednesday + 1);
  localStorage.setItem("storedTotalWednesday", currWednesday);

  const currTotalTasks = tasksFinishedTotal + 1;
  const wedAvg = (Math.round((currWednesday / currTotalTasks)*100));
  setAvgWednesday(wedAvg); 
  localStorage.setItem("storedAvgWed", wedAvg);
}
```